# JMeter - Thread Users gone after a few mins when set loop forever and schedule time

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan with five thread groups, each of them has 10 thread users, i wanna run this test plan for 1 hour with 50 concurrent users, for my understanding the number of thread users should keep at 50, but somehow thread users keep reducing after several mins, and ends with 0 thread user, below is my configurations, can someone help take a look, thanks in advance.

[image]

Also in jemter command, i got the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above error shows you got OOM i.e. Out Of Memory error.
You ran out of JMeter allocated heap space.

To resolve this issue you can try below things,

1. Use tips provided here (use non-gui mode, avoid heavy reporters etc.)
   http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips
2. Try to increase heap space of JMeter if your load test really requires large amount of heap space.

I would suggest follow suggestions sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using distributed setup for load testing , this way you can distribute the load in several machine

The quick fixes

1 Use JMeter in non-GUI mode

Find where you installed JMeter through command line or the terminal
Set the ‘bin’ directory as your current directory
Run ‘jmeter –n –t .jmx
That’s it, when your test is complete you can do your analysis. You may be interested in seeing how your test is performing  during execution in command line/terminal (rather than seeing a black window), to do this just uncomment the following within the JMeter properties file (remove the ‘#’):

summariser.name=summary

summariser.interval=180

summariser.out=true

2 Remove or at least disable listeners you don’t need. Typically listeners such as the ‘View Results Tree’ consume large amounts of memory purely down to how much information it gathers.

Simply take a second look at your script and remove the listeners you don’t need.
3Increase the JMeter heap memory

Within your explorer find where you installed JMeter
Open up the bin directory.
Find the ‘JMeter.bat’ file and open it with a text editor
Find the following ‘set HEAP’
You can set this HEAP value to whatever you like, in this example I’ve said allocate 2 GB of memory from the start and throughout the test run: ‘set HEAP=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m’